# How to set the Nav Bar collapse on large screen size using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, navbar

I want to set the set the menu bar to collapsed even on large screen. How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override this default style in bootstrap css

Here is the code to override and show menu bar to collapse in large scren

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: No collapsing by overriding